# Is convertapi also still very slow for you?

Tags: convertapi

We are using http://do.convertapi.com/Web2Pdf since 2013 and it was working very well till now, but since about 1 hour it is very, very slow and takes minimum 15 seconds for generating a PDF.
Also sometimes it takes also more then minutes!

Is this also happening for other users or just for us in Austria, maybe a connection problem to their servers headed in Lithuania?

Comment: Today in the morning (08:36 CET) I got the following email from convertapi.com about their service:   Our service was published on well know .NET blog and re-blogged on hundred others.
We received  hundreds of new users with thousands of API calls. We have added several new cloud machines and the problem was solved.

We are sorry for downtime.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is working faster again, because now I'm only waiting ca. 5 seconds in average.